# How with lighthouse graphql read data from external api?

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Starting with lighthouse library graphql in laravel app I use graphql-playground url for working with requests string

I in which way I can read data from external url and get paginated data with “/graphql” url ?

I managed to make it with custom query command :

```
php artisan lighthouse:query items
```

But to run it I had in type declaration to remove @paginate directive - looks like with it my custom query was not run, but default query only was run

```
type Query {

    items: [Item!]
    # @paginate(defaultCount: 5)
```

but with my query command I can not pass page and count parameter, like :

```
items(page: 1, count: 10)
{
    fieldname
}
```

I need somehow to run my custom query with @paginate.
How can I assign it ?

**ATTEMPT TO FIX 1:**

Looking at link
https://lighthouse-php.com/6/api-reference/directives.html#builder
with example :

```
type Query {
    users(
        minimumHighscore: Int @builder(method: "App\MyClass@minimumHighscore")
    ): [User!]! @all
    highrankedUsers: [User!]! @all @builder(method: "App\MyClass@minimumHighscore", value: 1000)
}
```

I remade my query :

```
type Query {
    items: [Item!] @paginate(defaultCount: 5) @builder(method: "App\\GraphQL\\Queries\\Items")
}
```

But I got error :

```
"debugMessage": "App\\GraphQL\\Queries\\Items::__invoke(): Argument #2 ($args) must be of type array, null given, called in /Project/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Directives/BuilderDirective.php on line 74",
"file": "/Project/app/GraphQL/Queries/Items.php",
"line": 13,
"trace": [
  {
```

line == 13 above that is line in custom query app/GraphQL/Queries/Items.php:

```
public function __invoke($_, array $args) // line13
{
```

I set possible null to :

```
public function __invoke($_, ?array $args)
{

    \Log::info(' -1 $args::'); // I see NULL values here

    $response = Http::get('https://external-api.com/items');


    $items = [];
    $tempItems = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
    foreach( $tempItems as $tempItem ) {
        $items[] = [
            'fieldname' => $tempItem->fieldname,
            ...
        ];
    }

    return $items;
}
```

But I got error :

```
"debugMessage": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\BuilderDirective::handleFieldBuilder(): Return value must be of type Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder|Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder|Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\Relation, array returned",
```

Which way is correct ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read  ATTEMPT TO FIX 1

Comment: You probably need to use the `@field`-directive instead of the `@builder`-directive. The Builder-directive is for using with Eloquent-Query-Builders.